# Problems importing function with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, export, webpack-4

Using webpack I am trying to export a function  from domManipulation.js to index.js, they are both in src folder

```
export function displayPage(pageToDisplay) {
  pageToDisplay.classlist.remove("hide");
  pagesArray.forEach((page) => {
    if (page !== pageToDisplay) {
      page.classList.add("hide");
    }
  });
}
```

using
`import { displayPage } from "./domManipulation.js";`

but in index.js  vs code just greys out as if the import text isn't working. If I right click on `displayPage` and select go to definition vs code takes my to the function so I guess it knows where the import statement is pointing to? However if I try and run the function in the chrome console on index.html from the dist folder I get `displayPage(ADD_EDIT_PAGE); VM18270:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: displayPage is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1`

Please help and be kind I literally started using webpack like 2 days ago!

below is the  the webpack config, the full code from the file I am trying to export the function from and the code from the module as it appears in chrome.

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  // watch: true,
  mode: 'development',
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

```
const DELETE_TODO_PAGE = document.getElementById("deleteTodoPage");
const CLEAR_COMPLEATED_PAGE = document.getElementById("clearCompleatedPage");
const NOTES_PAGE = document.getElementById("notesPage");
const TODO_PAGE = document.getElementById("todoPage");
const ADD_EDIT_PAGE = document.getElementById("addEditPage");

let pagesArray = [
  DELETE_TODO_PAGE,
  CLEAR_COMPLEATED_PAGE,
  NOTES_PAGE,
  TODO_PAGE,
  ADD_EDIT_PAGE,
];

export function displayPage(pageToDisplay) {
  pageToDisplay.classlist.remove("hide");
  pagesArray.forEach((page) => {
    if (page !== pageToDisplay) {
      page.classList.add("hide");
    }
  });
}
```

```
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "displayPage", function() { return displayPage; });
const DELETE_TODO_PAGE = document.getElementById("deleteTodoPage");
const CLEAR_COMPLEATED_PAGE = document.getElementById("clearCompleatedPage");
const NOTES_PAGE = document.getElementById("notesPage");
const TODO_PAGE = document.getElementById("todoPage");
const ADD_EDIT_PAGE = document.getElementById("addEditPage");

function displayPage(pageToDisplay) {
  let pagesArray = [
    DELETE_TODO_PAGE,
    CLEAR_COMPLEATED_PAGE,
    NOTES_PAGE,
    TODO_PAGE,
    ADD_EDIT_PAGE,
  ];
  pageToDisplay.classlist.remove("hide");
  pagesArray.forEach((page) => {
    if (page !== pageToDisplay) {
      page.classList.add("hide");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you put the ```webpack config``` as well? also check the build is getting success or not

Comment: @HidaytRahman done :-)